# method of querying main image for wiki pages works for some pages but not others

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to query the main image of the Wikipedia page for the Prime Minister of the UK: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_the_United_Kingdom

I got this method from various posts on StackOverflow. The problem is, for the PM's page, it returns the first image on the right-hand side of the page which is the Royal Coat of Arms. But when I query the page for the [Home Secretary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Secretary) in the same way, it correctly returns the second image which is the portrait of the incumbent Home Sec Suella Braverman. You can see for yourself if you swap out `pmPageID` with `HomeSecPageID` in this line: `result = getQuery(query.format(pmPageID))`

Here is my code:

```
import requests
# import re
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask import jsonify
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from flask import Flask, render_template
# from urllib.request import urlopen

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

def getQuery(search):
    response = requests.get(search)
    results = response.json()
    return jsonify(results)

pmPageID = 24150
HomeSecPageID = 149104
query = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&pageids={}'
@app.route('/')
@cross_origin()
def index():
    result = getQuery(query.format(pmPageID))
    return result
```

My question is, is there anything else I can do to pull the image of the incumbent prime minister?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [example use](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Albert%20Einstein&pithumbsize=100) of `pageimages` in the documentation only returns one result, despite the target article containing more images and adding `&pilimit=10`  makes no difference (it should default to 50).

You can access all the images in that article using `images` instead e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=images&format=json&titles=Prime_Minister_of_the_United_Kingdom&imlimit=100&imdir=descending but for some reason, that returns the images in a random order compared to how you see them in the article. The one you're after is ninth in that list, but if edits are made to the article, that could change.

Comment: I tried using the wikidata api sandbox: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=wbgetentities&format=json&ids=Q42&sites=enwiki&titles=Prime%20Minister%20of%20the%20United%20Kingdom&props=claims&formatversion=2

Right at the bottom of the query result, (key is P18), there is some info about Rishi Sunak's image but no URL to access it. Do you know how I can access it? Here is the query URL: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&ids=Q42&sites=enwiki&titles=Prime%20Minister%20of%20the%20United%20Kingdom&props=claims&formatversion=2

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Official%20portrait%20of%20Rishi%20Sunak%20crop%202%20(cropped).jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url